# Where can I find the specific details of a gravity assist space mission?

Tags: voyager, gravity-assist, jpl-horizons, cassini, galileo

0

I am writing a research essay where I need to know the specific details of a gravity assist mission such as Voyager 2's flyby of Jupiter for example (but any mission would work as long as it is a flyby and I have the specific details). I am looking for incoming velocity, exit velocity, mass of spacecraft, periapsis altitude, argument of periapsis, inclination, trajectories. I basically need all the information to do any gravity assist calculation and I am unable to find at least 1 mission where all of this is released (I have been primarily looking at NASA and the JPL Horizons).

When I google gravity assist on Wikipedia I see a bunch of simulations of the trajectories of spacecrafts performing a gravity assist (including Voyager 1, Voyager 2, Galileo - but again any one would work, I just need sufficient data for one mission). I figured that since the trajectory simulation is public there must be a place where all the un-processed data exists. If anyone knows where I could find this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30420/12102) mentions the Interplanetary Mission Design Handbook. While the link has rotted these have similar names and may be useful; [1](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100037210.pdf), [2](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19840010158.pdf), [3](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980210557.pdf), [4](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325130492_Interplanetary_Mission_Design_Handbook_Earth-to-Mars_Mission_Opportunities_and_Mars-to-Earth_Return_Opportunities_2009_-_2024)

Comment: Also see links in comments on and answers to [How to understand this complicated plot for Mariner 4's mid-course correction (to Mars)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30353/12102) and to [Gravitational keyhole for spacecraft flyby?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37273/12102) and to [Calculating spacecraft thrust manoeuvres with JPL data](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25817/12102) and to [STK Astrogator Earth Flyby](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39471/12102)

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  In addition to the posts linked to by uhoh, have you tried searching on this site?  Some of the tags you have selected for this question -- particularly the [tag:gravity-assist] tag -- will have information related to what you are looking for.  Clicking on the tags will give you a list of questions with that tag.

Comment: Uh, what is the JPL Horizons?  New Horizons was built and run from the Applied Physics Laboratory (APL), which beat out JPL for the Pluto mission.  Alan Stern and David Grinspoon devote pages, in the plural, to that event in _Chasing New Horizons_.